# Como mostrar una imagen de una api?

Tags: flutter, dart

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar la imagen que está en poster_path (en la api) y tendría que ir al lado de cada titulo. Si no se puede traer la imagen de poster path de cada titulo y mostrarla, se me ocurre que podría descargar cada una pero sería mejor si se puede traer de la api cada una.

Esta es la api: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=&language=en-US&page=1

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
//Step 3
  _HomeScreenState() {
    _filter.addListener(() {
      if (_filter.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _searchText = "";
          filteredNames = titulos;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _searchText = _filter.text;
        });
      }
    });
  }

//Step 1
  final TextEditingController _filter = new TextEditingController();
  final dio = new Dio(); // for http requests
  String _searchText = "";
  List titulos = new List(); // titulos we get from API
  List filteredNames = new List(); // names filtered by search text
```

Comment: Recomendación: elimina el enlace del API porque contiene tu APIKEY y eso debería ser privado.

Comment: perfecto!! muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las imágenes en [TheMovieDB](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images) estan en la ruta: https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500.

Podrías usar un componente similar a este, donde tendrías un objeto que representa cada entrada de *Movie* en el json de respuesta de la API, después simplemente usando [Image.network](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) puedes traerte esa imagen sin tener que almacenarla:

```
class MoviePoster extends StatelessWidget {
  const MoviePoster(this.movie);
  final Movie movie;
  final String imagePrefix = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: movie.id,
      child: movie.posterPath == null
          ? Icon(
              Icons.movie,
              size: 48,
            )
          : Image.network(
              imagePrefix + movie.posterPath,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactamente, pero yo digo usando esta api: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=0e685fd77fb3d76874a3ac26e0db8a4b&language=en-US&page=1 que es la que tiene las 10 peliculas más populares, tambien tiene el id, el titulo, la fecha de salida y el poster path de la imagen, esa es la que yo necesito para poder mostrar el poster path del primer titulo, despues del segundo y así hasta el decimo.

Comment: es la misma api, pero las imagenes se encuentran en la URL que te digo :), (tmdb.org es un alias de themoviedb). Puedes leerlo aqui: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images

Comment: Ahhh okay, una cosa, podrías mandarme el link una vez más porque me aparece 'file not found'  Gracias!!

Comment: He actualizado la respuestas con el link, recuerda puntuar los comentarios o respuestas que te hayan podido parecer útiles para que ayude a los demás que tengan las mismas dudas.

Comment: Claro, pero el problema es que me sale 'file not found' puede ser que sea mi pc?

Comment: recuerda que la URL _empieza_ por https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500 luego debes ponerle el posterPath, por ejemplo https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/pgqgaUx1cJb5oZQQ5v0tNARCeBp.jpg

Comment: perfecto, muchisimas gracias!!! ahí acepté la respuesta!!